# Are there any natural numbers $n$ that satisfy the condition $7921\sigma(n) = 15840n$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, divisor-sum

Are there any natural numbers $n$ that satisfy the condition $7921\sigma(n) = 15840n$, where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisors of $n$?

This question arises from the theory of immaculate groups (or, equivalently, Leinster groups). An immaculate group is a group, such that its order is equal to the sum of all orders of its proper normal subgroups.

It is easy to see, that if $A$ is a non-abelian simple group then $A\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is immaculate iff $(|A|+1)\sigma(n) = 2|A|n$. Two well known examples of immaculate groups of that form are $A_5\times\mathbb{Z}_{15128}$ and $A_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{366776}$. In terms of immaculate groups this question thus can be reworded as:
"Does there exist such $n$, that $M_{11}\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is immaculate?", where $M_{11}$ stands for Mathieu simple group of order $7920$.

Currently I know only two facts about such $n$-s: if they exist, then $7921|n$, and that such $n$-s, if they exist, are too large to be found by exhaustive search.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like such a random question to ask until you see the entirely reasonable motivation.

Comment: @Arthur Tbh I saw a motivation at the start, this being essentially a question of how close $\sigma(n)$ can be to $2n$.

Comment: @fretty Near-perfect numbers are cool, but that's a _really_ specific ratio, though.

Comment: An explantion why it is hopeless to search such a number with brute force, would be nice.

Comment: I figured out a positive integer $n$ with $$7921\sigma(n)=2\cdot 15840\cdot n$$ $$n=563432025678613816032$$ Not sure whether this helps

Comment: I have tried hard to find a solution, but I failed. My conjecture is that there is no solution, but a proof will be very difficult considering that it is , for example , an open question whether there is an odd perfect number.

Comment: Seeing that $7921=89^2$ and $89$ is a prime number, I got the following result: if there is a solution $N$ such that $N$ is not a multiple of $89^3$, then $k=\frac{N}{89^2}$ is a solution for $8011\sigma(k)=15840k$

Comment: Asymptotically, or to a good degree of accuracy approximation wise, the number of unique values of the ratio $\frac{n}{\sigma(n)}$, if we restrict ourselves to a subset via imposing a predicate $max(n)=N$, is a linear function of N. So what this tells us seeings 7911 and 15840 are coprime, is that if that ratio is not encountered for the data up to say N=20000, then it does not exist for any $n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: 7921 sorry, and you can plot the data for what I have stated and review the regression to a linear least squares approximation for yourself, but it is well and truly impossible that you will encounter it beyond N=20000 I would say

Comment: But as far as this particular ratio is concerned in that set of ratios for all $n \in \mathbb N$, there is nothing really significant about it over any other value

Comment: @Dejan Govc  Fixed version is ready. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: This question is a lot easier to answer than the lengths everyone has gone to here @YuriNegometyanov if the cardinality of the set ${\{ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} :n \in \mathbb N \land n \lt N }\} $ has linear proportion to N, it means that increasing $N$ will add an element to that set in a linearly proportionate manner, thus if  we have not encountered the value up to around $N=20000$, (or appreciably greater that 15840 anyway) it is impossible it will ever be added by greater values of $N$

Comment: if 7921 and 15840 were not coprime, then I could never make this assertion, because there is an infinite number of $n$ for which could have our target ratio, but because they are coprime, I can know this ratio will never occur having computed values appreciably beyond the maximum of the denominator and numerator of our target ratio

Comment: @Adam Your issue thesis is wrong. Please read [there](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)

Comment: ok so just to clarify we are talking about the same function $$\sigma(n)=\sum _{k=1}^{n}\delta \left( n,k \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{k}}
 \Bigr\rfloor  \right) k
$$ correct? @YuriNegometyanov

Comment: @Adam If the question is too easy you can manage it yourself

Comment: I already have in the comments I have made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{Fixed\ version}}$$

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{Constraints\ of\ the\ task}}$$

The issue equation is
$$89^2\sigma(n)=2^53^25^111^1n.\tag1$$
Let WLOG
$$n=2^A3^B5^C11^D89^{U+2}m,\quad (A,B,C,D,U)\in\mathbb N\cup {0} ,\quad \gcd(m, 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot89)=1,\tag2$$
then $(1)$ [takes the form of](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) 
$$89^2\cdot\dfrac{2^{A+1}-1}1 \cdot\dfrac{3^{B+1}-1}2 \cdot\dfrac{5^{C+1}-1}4\cdot\dfrac{11^{D+1}-1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{89^{U+3}-1}{88}\cdot\sigma(m) =$$
$$2^{A+5}3^{B+2}5^{C+1}11^{D+1}89^{U+2}m,\tag3$$
or
$$\dfrac{2^{A+1}-1}{2^{A+1}}\cdot\dfrac{3^{B+1}-1}{3^{B+1}}\cdot\dfrac{5^{C+1}-1}{5^{C+1}}\cdot\dfrac{11^{D+1}-1}{11^{D+1}}\cdot\dfrac{89^{U+3}-1}{88\cdot89^U}\cdot\sigma(m) = 2^{8}\cdot3\cdot5\cdot{m},\tag4$$
$$\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{3^{-B}}3\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right)\cdot\dfrac{89^3-89^{-U}}{88}\cdot\sigma(m) = 3840m.\tag5$$
Easy to see that
$$\dfrac{89^3-89^{-U}}{88} \ge \dfrac{89^3-1}{88} = 8011.$$
At the same time, $\sigma(m)$ is the sum of divisors, so
$$\sigma(m)\ge 1+m.$$
Thus,
$$8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{3^{-B}}3\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right) \le 3840.\tag6$$
Similarly,
\begin{cases}
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\dfrac23\cdot\dfrac45\cdot\dfrac{10}{11} \le 3840\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{3^{-B}}3\right)\cdot\dfrac45\cdot\dfrac{10}{11} \le 3840\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right)\cdot\dfrac23\cdot\dfrac{10}{11} \le3840\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right)\cdot\dfrac23\cdot\dfrac45 \le 3840\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-1}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right)\cdot\dfrac23 \le 3840,\tag7\\
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right) \le 7920\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{3^{-B}}3\right) \le 5280\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right) \le 6336\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{2^{-A}}2\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right)\le 7200\\
8011\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{5^{-C}}5\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{11^{-D}}{11}\right) \le 7680,\quad A=1, \ B=0.\tag8\\
\end{cases}
The system $(8)$ has the solution
$$\left[
\begin{aligned}
&A=0\\
&A=1,\ B=0,\ C=D=1\\
&A=1,\ B=0,\ C>2\\
&A=2,\ B=C=0\\
&5\ge A\ge3,\ B=C=D=0, 
\end{aligned}\right.\tag9\\$$
or
$$\left[
\begin{align}
&2 \not|\ n\hspace{40pt}\\
&((n=2m)\vee(n=8m)\vee(n=16m)\vee(n=32m)\vee(n=110m))\\ &\quad\wedge(\gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11,m)=1)\\
&(n=50m)\wedge(\gcd(2\cdot3, m)=1)\\
&(n=4m)\wedge(\gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5,m)=1)\\
\end{align}\right..\tag{10}
$$

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{Applying\ of\ the\ constraints}}$$
Obtained constraints $(10)$ allow to filter the possible solutions.

At first, becames impossible the case
$$n=2^{10}89^3k.$$
Secondly, if
$$n=89^2\cdot8011\cdot2003\cdot167k,\quad \gcd(89\cdot167\cdot2003\cdot8011,k) = 1,$$
with the equation
$$28\sigma(k)=55k,$$
then 
\begin{cases}
49\sigma(m)=55m,\text{ if }k=4m,\ \gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5,m)=1 \\
21\sigma(m)=22m,\text{ if }k=8m,\ \gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11,m)=1 \\
31\cdot7\sigma(m)=4\cdot55m\text{ if }k=16m,\ \gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11,m)=1 \\
21^2\sigma(m)=8\cdot55m\text{ if }k=32m,\ \gcd(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11,m)=1 .\tag{11}
\end{cases}
Taking in account that
$$\sigma(7)=2^3,\quad\sigma(49)= 2^2\cdot5^2,$$
the system $(11)$ really can not be satisfied.

So I think that the issue equation $\mathbf{\color{brown}{has\ not\ solutions\ in\ the\ positive\ integer\ numbers.}}$

Comment: $m$ not divisible by 2, 3, 5, 11, and 89?

Comment: @qwr Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: I also think you should make clear where you obtained 6144 since it is not obvious to me. Also are A,B,C,D,U nonnegative or positive integers? Use $\mathbb{N}_0$ for nonnegative numbers

Comment: $\mathbb Z_+$ does not contain 0.

Comment: How did you get from $89^2\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{89^{U+1}-1}{88}$ to $\frac{89^{U+3}-1}{88}$?

Comment: Yes I feel like the answer can't be this simple, otherwise wouldn't odd perfect numbers be easily discredited?

Comment: @qwr Thanks for the comments, my answer becames better. The approach normally works for the even perfect numbers. And you're idea is nice, perfect odd numbers really does not exist =)

Comment: @qwr Really, I've dug a lot of the solution forms, but every time was stopped due to decreasing of the coefficients ratio.

Comment: The 89² is still wrong I think

Comment: @qwr Ready. Thank you for discussion.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: I believe that equation (3) is still wrong. I think the right-hand side should read $2^{11}\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot m$.

Comment: @jpvee Unfortunately, arithmetic does not allow options.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: I like the style of your comments - very poetic! But I don't understand what you are trying to say :)

Comment: @jpvee That the equation $(3)$ isn't wrong.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Thanks for the clarification. Then please tell me what you did to the $88$ in the denominator in the equation **before** (3) - I see that the $8$ has become part of the $2^{11}$ on the right-hand side of (3), but I do not see what became of the remaining $11$ of the $88=8\cdot 11$. Also the same question for the $10$ in the denominator. And finally, the $m$ vanished from the upper equation completely when going to (3).

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Interesting approach, but it seems to me jpvee is correct. Also, I think $\frac{506904}{3}$ should actually be $\frac{506944}{3}$.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: It's looking somewhat better now, but in the right-hand side of (3), I'm still missing the $5$ (coming from the denominator $10$ in the equation above). And with that, your inequality unfortunately no longer holds.

Comment: @jpvee You're right at all, current version isn't right. My severe typo masked this fact. On the other hand, I've found the hard way to fix this proof, and I plan to do this at some hours.

Comment: @jpvee The final version is presented. Thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score 8):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment, that should help anyone interested in using brute-force numerical search to find the solution.

---

The problem is to find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which
$$7921 \sigma(n) = 15840 n \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all divisors of $n$, as defined in the Wikipedia [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) article, and as a sequence in [OEIS A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203).

Because $\sigma(n) = n + 1$ if $n$ is a prime, and
$$7921 (n + 1) \ne 15840 n, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$
we already know there is no prime solution to $\eqref{NA1}$.

---

Consider the prime factorization of $n$. Let $p_i \in \mathbb{N}$ be nonrepeating primes ($p_i = p_j$ if and only if $i = j$), and $1 \le k_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then,
$$n = \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} p_i^{k_i}$$
and
$$\sigma(n) = \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{p_i^{k_i+1} - 1}{p_i - 1}$$
because $\sigma(p^k) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} p^j = (p^{k+1}-1)/(p-1)$ when $p$ is a prime.

We can now rewrite the problem $\eqref{NA1}$ as
$$7921 \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{p_i^{k_i+1} - 1}{p_i - 1} = 15840 \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} p_i^{k_i} \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
Rearranging the terms yields
$$\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{ p_i^{k_i + 1} - p_i^{k_i} }{ p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1 } = \frac{7921}{15840} = \frac{n}{\sigma(n)} = \frac{89^2}{2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11}
\tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
Note the term
$$f_i = \frac{ p_i^{k_i + 1} - p_i^{k_i} }{ p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1 } = \frac{p_i^{k_i}}{\sum_{j=0}^{k_i} p^j}, \quad \frac{1}{2} \lt f_i \lt 1
\tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
i.e.,
$$\begin{array}{ll}
f_i = \frac{p_i}{p_i + 1}, & k_i = 1 \\
f_i = \frac{p_i^2}{p_i^2 + p_i + 1}, & k_i = 2 \\
f_i = \frac{p_i^3}{p_i^3 + p_i^2 + p_i + 1 }, & k_i = 3 \\
f_i = \frac{p_i^{k_i}}{p_i^{k_i} + p_i^{k_i-1} + \dots + p_i + 1 } & \\ 
\end{array}$$

Thus, the numerical search problem is now reduced to find the set of terms $f_i$ based on primes $p_i$ and their positive powers $k_i$, so that the product $$\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} f_i = \frac{7921}{15840}$$
In particular, because $f_i \lt 1$, a particular set can be rejected immediately if the product falls below the target ratio.

---

For example, if $p_0 = 89$, $k_0 = 2$, to eliminate the prime factor in the numerator. Repeating, that leads to $p_1 = 8011$, $k_1 = 1$; $p_2 = 2003$, $k_2 = 1$; and $p_3 = 167$, $k_3 = 1$, to get us to a result with a composite numerator and a denominator:
$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
n & \frac{n}{\sigma(n)} & \frac{15840 n}{7921 \sigma(n)} \\
\hline
   89^2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 2003 \cdot 167
& \frac{7921}{8064} = \frac{7921}{2^7 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7}
& \frac{55}{28} = \frac{5 \cdot 11}{2^2 \cdot 7}
\\ 89^2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 2003 \cdot 167 \cdot 7
& \frac{7921}{9216} = \frac{7921}{2^{10} \cdot 3^2}
& \frac{55}{32} = \frac{5 \cdot 11}{2^5}
\\ 89^2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 2003 \cdot 167 \cdot 2
& \frac{7921}{12096} = \frac{7921}{2^6 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 7}
& \frac{55}{42} = \frac{5 \cdot 11}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7}
\\ 89^2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 2003 \cdot 167 \cdot 2 \cdot 7
& \frac{7921}{13824} = \frac{7921}{2^9 \cdot 3^3}
& \frac{55}{48} = \frac{5 \cdot 11}{2^4 \cdot 3}
\\ 89^2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 2003 \cdot 167 \cdot 2^2 
& \frac{7921}{14112} = \frac{7921}{2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^2}
& \frac{55}{49} = \frac{5 \cdot 11}{7^2}
\\ \end{array}$$
If you append $p_5 = 7$, $k_5 = 1$ or $k_5 = 2$ to $n$ in the final row above, the rightmost field drops below 1 (to $55/56$ for $k_5 = 1$, and to $55/57$ for $k_5 = 2$), leading nowhere. Similarly, appending $p_6 = 3$, $k_6 = 1$ or $k_6 = 2$ to $n$ in the second-to-last row (to $55/64$ for $k_6 = 1$, and to $165/208$ for $k_6 = 2$) leads nowhere.

It looks to (very non-mathematician) me that an exhaustive search over primes $p$ is possible, due to terms $f_i$ having a power of a prime in the numerator, as specified in $\eqref{NA4}$. Whether an exhaustive search is possible or not is an open question (and is important for those looking for proof), but the efficient numerical brute force search strategies are straightforward; especially if one is looking for some other ratios than $\frac{n}{\sigma(n)} = \frac{7921}{15840}$.

To continue the search above, I'd need a prime $p$ and a positive integer $k$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^{k} p^j = 55$ (to yield a factor with denominator $55$). No such pair exists, so the search strategies I've come up with thus far are exhausted.

---

Hopefully, one of the math sages here can take this further from here.

Comment: This is the way to the jungle. For example, the equality $2^{11}-1=23\cdot89$ requires consideration of the variant $k_0=3$ etc.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: At first glance, using $2^{10}$ does indeed look promising. Unfortunately, however, $\frac{89^3}{\sigma(89^3)}\cdot\frac{2^{10}}{\sigma(2^{10})}$ is already below the target ratio of $\frac{7921}{15840}$. In fact, if you use $k_0=3$, then the largest power of $2$ that may appear in $n$ is $2^5$.

Comment: I do believe my efforts stalled, because rewriting $\eqref{NA2}$ as $\eqref{NA3}$ places an additional constraint on the coefficients. I really should rewrite $\eqref{NA2}$ to use another index variable, say $j$, on the right side.  Similarly, the indexing in the numerator and denominator in $\eqref{NA3}$ do not need to be the same. @YuriNegometyanov: Is this what you meant by the way to the jungle (off the track)?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I mean the jungles of variants in the situation where solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @jpvee I've shown that the target ratio can not be satisfied at all,

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: I don't think your proof works - see my comment regarding the right-hand side in equation (3).

Comment: @jpvee Your brave hypothesis should be based on the exact calculations.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer either: I have written a program doing a non-exhaustive search, and so far, no solutions have come up for the Mathieu group $M_{11}$; however, the program did find a solution e.g. for the larger Mathieu group $M_{22}$ of order $443520=2^7\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11$:

Let $n=55009909630=2\cdot5\cdot13\cdot79\cdot109\cdot157\cdot313$, then since $$
\begin{align}
(|M_{22}|+1)\cdot\sigma(n)&=443521\cdot\sigma(2\cdot5\cdot13\cdot79\cdot109\cdot157\cdot313) \\
&=13\cdot109\cdot313\cdot3\cdot6\cdot14\cdot80\cdot110\cdot158\cdot314 \\
&=2^9\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot79\cdot109\cdot157\cdot313 \\
&=2\cdot|M_{22}|\cdot n\text{,}\end{align}$$
$M_{22}\times\mathbb{Z}_{55009909630}$ must be immaculate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution to this problem might be realized via an application of the latest results of Holdener, et. al. on abundancy outlaws?

[Holdener, Weiner (2014) - Searching for and Characterizing Abundancy Outlaws](http://biology.kenyon.edu/HHMI/posters_2014/weinerz.pdf)

[Holdener, Moore (2011) - A Geometric Representation of the Abundancy Index](http://biology.kenyon.edu/HHMI/posters_2011/moorek.pdf)

[Holdener, Czarnecki (2008) - The Abundancy Index: Tracking Down Outlaws](http://biology.kenyon.edu/HHMI/posters_2007/CzarneckiL.png)

[Holdener, Stanton (2007) - Abundancy "Outlaws" of the Form $\frac{\sigma(N) + t}{N}$](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Holdener/holdener7.pdf)